# How to iterate through a list of literals in Emacs lisp?

Tags: list, lisp, elisp

I want to replace text in an Emacs buffer and this function works:

```lisp
(defun sanitize-md ()
  "Replace characters."
  (interactive)
  (query-replace "\\" "/" nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (query-replace "ﬁ" "fi" nil (point-min) (point-max))
  )
```

I want to refactor it with a list with:

```lisp
(defun sanitize-md ()
  "Replace characters."
  (interactive)
  (let (replacement-list '("\\" "/" "ﬁ" "fi"))
    (while (progn
         (let* (
            (to-find (pop replacement-list))
            (to-replace (pop replacement-list))
            )
           (query-replace to-find to-replace nil (point-min) (point-max)))
         (replacement-list)
         ))))
```

But this throws an error `Invalid function: "\\"`, even though I quoted the declaration of the list. I think I am getting confused with LISP's system of quotes and functions at the start of a list, so I tried `(let (replacement-list '(list "\\" "/" "ﬁ" "fi"))` and got another error `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

How to iterate through a list of literals in LISP until it is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the `let` form's syntax. The first argument should be a list of lists, not just a single list.

Also, you will want to use `(interactive "*")` to avoid attempting to modify content which is read-only.  And the `let*` form (where you are already using the correct syntax!) is already a single form, so you can take out the `progn`.

Finally, `replacement-list` is not a function, so you should take out the parentheses around it in the last expression.

```lisp
(defun sanitize-md ()
  "Replace characters."
  (interactive "*")
  (let ((replacement-list '("\\" "/" "ﬁ" "fi")))
    (while (let* ((to-find (pop replacement-list))
                  (to-replace (pop replacement-list)) )
             (query-replace to-find to-replace nil (point-min) (point-max))
             replacement-list))) ))
```

It would perhaps be more idiomatic to make `replacement-list` be a list of conses with `to-find` and `to-replace` values, but this should at least get you back up onto the road.

Note that when `replacement-list` is the last form of of the `let*` structure, that is then what the `while` expression evaluates, thus ending the loop when the list is empty. If `query-replace` were the last form in the condition of `while`, the loop would end when no match is found. See [this other thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60233/query-replace-stops-after-first-item-in-while/60237#60237).

Comment: You're right on all counts. I missed the single parenthesis in the `let` form. Can you include the more idiomatic syntax with the list of conses?

Comment: Simply `(let ((replacement-list '(("\\" . "/") ("ﬁ" . "fi"))))` and pluck off one pair at a time.

Comment: I made it work without the period. Why do you have a period in the middle of each list?

Comment: That's what makes it a [cons.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) Though it's not hard to do with lists either, just a tad less efficient.

Comment: Got it! I got an error because I was popping the cons twice. It works when using `car` and `cdr` on the conses.

Comment: @tripleee - while I strongly agree with using `conses` for this, `query-replace` doesn't mind using a `("string")` as its replacement, although as far as I know, it isn't documented to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `dolist` macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/dolist.html) to easily walk a list of patterns and their replacements. In the solution below I've made them pairs in the list so that both are accessible at each iteration:

```
(defun sanitize-md ()
  "Replace characters."
  (interactive "*")
  (dolist (from-to '(("\\" "/") ("ﬁ" "fi")))
    (query-replace (car from-to) (cdr from-to) nil (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Comment: Probably better (more widely applicable) if you use conses instead of pairs, so that `car` and `cdr` just grab the strings.  In your example, `(cdr from-to)` grabs the list segment, e.g. `("/")` instead of `"/"`.  For `query-replace` it doesn't matter, but that's a  specific virtue of that function. You could also use `cadr` to grab the `car` of `cdr`.  Using `cons` and `car` / `cdr` really makes a lot of tasks simpler in Lisp.

Comment: I should also note that (as  far as I know) `query-replace` handling the `TO-STRING` argument as a list is undocumented.